# How Windows Server 2008 generates list of known licensing servers & how to specify license server via script?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, rds

I'm wondering how Windows Server 2008 generates known license server lists (where it's stored and when/how updated) for RDS, and as RD Session Host Configuration Console doesn't allow multiple select when adding license server I'm also looking for a way to specify license servers via script (PS is preferable).

I guess this list is stored in Registry and I can read values and use them in my script to specify license servers but I guess there could be better options for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following can be used for adding all Known license severs to Specified license servers with PowerShell:

```
import-module remotedesktopservices
cd RDS:\RDSConfiguration\LicensingSettings\SpecifiedLicenseServers
dir ..\RegisteredLicenseServers | new-item -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Remote Desktop License Servers store their licensing information in Active Directory. You can view it using the AD Sites & Services snap-in.

Comment: So it looks like when license server role is installed it publish ingo in AD, does other servers which reads this info filter it somehow? E.g. in mixed environments where both WS2003/2008 license servers are exist and not all license servers capable to provide appropriate licenses.